# How to access internet behind proxy with authentication

Tags: wi-fi, networking, proxy

Our University provides internet behind a http proxy. To use internet we need to go through a http proxy server (proxy address and port) with authentication (username and password). Also the external DNS servers are not reachable from our institute network. We have our own DNS servers (addresses known).

As Android does not have any option to use proxy authentication with Wi-Fi and moreover all the apps does not obey android proxy settings we usually used [Drony](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy.drony&hl=en). For a non rooted device it creates a local VPN (with proxy authentication) and compel all the apps to pass through the VPN to connect internet. Everything was mostly fine.

The problem begins with upgrades beyond Kitkat (Android 4.4). Drony stopped working. It is a robust app with lots of options. I made a few changes but not succeeded and now kind of lost. I have tried few alternate  apps for non-rooted devices like Psiphon (got large delay over network) and proxyauth (few apps do not obey its VPN) but their performances are not as satisfactory as Drony.

Could you please tell me how can I use Drony (setting details) in Android 6? Other way it will also be a great help if you suugets any app that can reach the internet through the above network settings for a **non-rooted** device.

Comment: As *Drony* was just updated a few weeks ago, did you approach the dev with the issue? He should know best how to fix that up.

Comment: I completely agree. I did not think about it. Will try to contact the dev. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to keep us updated once you got a response. Also consider to [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) when solved :) Good luck!

Comment: Surely I will do. In the mean time any advise is welcome.

Comment: Be welcome to check my list of [Proxy](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_proxy#group_406) apps. Looks like the top-rated candidate (Shadowsocks) meets your requirements as well. As I haven't tested any of them, I cannot post an answer, though.